# www.sandbox.itunes.apple.com is down

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Specific Question:** Since I get an error -1001 "Cannot connect to iTunes store" when testing in-app purchase in the sandbox environment :

1. Is it important to know if `www.sandbox.itunes.apple.com` is down?
2. If not, how will I know whether Apple's sandbox is down?

**Background:** I am working on adding In-App purchases to my iOS app and testing in the sandbox. I am able to receive the `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse` method, and receive the array of products.
My problem arises when I add a SKPayment to the SKPaymentQueue.

**I have done:**

1. specific appID with matching provisioning profiles (no * in com.company.appname)
2. downloaded them in xcode
3. my app's bundle identifier matches what I have in #1 as well as in iTunesConnect
4. updated Xcode settings (Code signing, etc as stated in [Troy Bryant's tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/comment-page-3/#comment-20901))
5. Registered the app and products in iTunesConnect
6. Submitted, rejected binary (status is again Waiting for Upload)
7. Used code from Ray Wenderlich tutorial (this code was working in another test app before but I deleted that test project)
8. Added a test user in iTunesConnect
9. Sign-out from appstore before testing
10. Others: delete app then test again; total reset of iPhone
11. waited 24 hours after the last changes in iTunesConnect

If you have other suggestions kindly help. My main question though is on how to know if the sandbox server is the one having problems.

Comment: I'm in the same trouble. Always 1001 but I can get my products info well. Yesterday night (Italy time) the problem went away but today I'm again stuck with this.

Comment: It's definitely an Apple issue since now I can use the sandbox again. :)

Comment: Now  I could not even get the array of products. I have not changed anything. The error that I was able to catch is the same -1001 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

Answer (score 1):

My sandbox in-app purchase suddenly worked. It seems like sandbox servers are up now. I am now in the position to answer my first noob question above: 1. Checking if www.sandbox.itunes.apple.com is up is not the way to test whether the sandbox servers are up or not. www.sandbox.itunes.apple.com is still down but my sandbox in-app purchase is working. I still do not  have the answer for number 2. Thanks microspino for giving the time to provide  your observation.